# Check if local and online file are the same on Dropbox

Tags: android, file, synchronization, dropbox

I am backing up my app to the dropbox.

Is it possible, to check, if the local file (a new one) is the same as the one on the server?

My idea would be a second file with a file hash, but I would like to know if there's already a simplier or more common way to do that...

Comment: Are you suing Dropbox-Sync API ?

Comment: yes, I'm using the official dropbox api for android

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DropBox Sync API then AFAICT you can make a call to 
[DBFileStatus cached] 
of the file in question to see if it's the same,
Fergal